# username rewriting taking last /

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I've been trying to do is to rewrite url from domain.com?profile.php?id=foo to domain.com/foo and this condition works, and in the php to get the username i use

```
$_GET['id']
```

And it works untill i add another / at the end of url, for example if i want to make something like domain.com/user/photos or just domain.com/user/ then $_GET['id'] gets user/ instead of only user, I hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)([^/]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]


DirectoryIndex home.php
```

profile.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'db.php';

include_once('assets/language.php');
include_once 'languages/'.$langfile;


// Processing post and registering user
include('assets/posts.php');

$pageTitle = $_GET['id'];
include('functions/functions.php');
include('assets/header.php');

if(!logged_in()) 
{
    header("location: home");
    exit();
}

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $username = $_GET['id'];

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        include('assets/content/view_profile.php');
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: home");
        exit();         
    }
} 
else
{
    header("location: home");
    exit();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if file with .php extension exists before rewriting it, and add an optional trailing slash to your User rule'pattern, try

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
RewriteEngine on
#1)rewrite /file to /file.php
#if file.php exists in filesystem
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
#rewrite /file to /file.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC]
#2)rewrite /user/ or /user to /profile.php?id=user
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: now im getting object not found, i don't know if it matters, but the project isnt in localhost/home.php its in localhost/blog/home.php

Comment: every. if i go to for example localhost/blog/register it gives me object not found, while on register.php its ok

Comment: I think it's due to the rule's destination as its pointing to the root folder. I have fixed it . Try the updated rule.

Comment: okay, it works now for the register and other things, and for username untill i put alst / like .com/user/ it redirects me to
http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/profile.php?id=user/

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: No, only the one you gave me

Comment: Ok then what exactly is the problem? could you explain it clearly?

Comment: Okay, I'll give my best. So the part where I'm removing .php extension from the URL works, for example localhost/blog/register.php is now only /blog/register. But the part where it's supposed to rewrite localhost/blog/profile.php?id=johndoe to localhost/blog/johndoe works untill I add / to the end of username example: localhost/blog/johndoe/ when i add that last / it redirects me to http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/profile.php?id=cadilab/ not even rewriting the url

Comment: Not sure why your server is redirecting the request. The rule is ok and works fine for me.

Comment: Just figured out that http://localhost/blog/profile.php?id=user is not redirecting me to localhost/blog/user

Comment: Turns out that the google chrome caching and cookies were the problem, it works now, thanks !